# R studio restore R markdown file to previous version from a while ago after I created a new project. How do I get my recent file back?

Tags: r

SO I was trying to set up a new project in r studio when I had a couple of files open in r studio. When I created the project, It reset my r markdown file to its contents from 2 months ago randomly. Before I created the new project, I wasn't using a project. Like the file has been reset to code I used a long time ago and I had saved over countless times. Is there any way I can get the contents from the R markdown file. Also, I still have most of the contents in my workspace, is there a way to turn my workspace into code quickly?

Comment: Strange. Were you using any version control systems like [git](https://git-scm.com/) or similar?

Comment: I tried to use version control systems, but I didn't actually change the version. I only opened up the option in the settings.

Comment: Very strange for a file to revert for no reason. Do you know what version control system you were using/not using? if you got to your working directory and type `ls -a` into the terminal (`dir /ah` if you're using windows) do you see a directory called `.git`?

Comment: No, I don't .git in my directory.

Comment: This is really strange indeed. Just for your own safety in the future, use git or do your work on cloud platform such as Dropbox, OneDrive or Google Drive so you can restore to previous versions when needed